# How to get rid of unwanted chinese characters?

Tags: c, windows

I am learning to create simple Windows applications and my first attempt is to create a pop-up with a message and ok button. I am doing this in C using visual C++ 2012. My issue is the window pops up but its header and the message is in chinese? I am doing everything in english so any idea why this is happening and how to fix??

FYI heres the code:

```
#include<windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "Hello", "Warning", MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: If i had to guess:  You're compiling for Unicode, but using `char` strings.  I'd have thought that would trigger at least a warning, but eh.  See if spelling your strings like `TEXT("Hello")` helps.

Comment: I'm surprised the compiler didn't outright-barf on this if the wide message box API is being invoked with narrow strings. Unless, of course, this isn't the real code and it actually has hard-casts to `(LPCWSTR)` that aren't shown here.

Comment: Ok it is a duplicate of that other question, sorry i tried searching but couldnt find anything. Also using `TEXT("Hello")` has fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Change the call to this:

```
MessageBox(NULL, L"Hello", L"Warning", MB_OK);
```

A quick test (that produced compiler warnings C4133) showed the unexpected characters being displayed if you call MessageBoxW (the Unicode entrypoint) with non-Unicode strings.

Comment: +1 hovering the mouse over the `MessageBox` identifier will equally display the tooltip `MessageBoxA` or `MessageBoxW`, a edit-time check that you should be passing narrow or wide strings respectively (the compile-time check should fail regardless if your passing the wrong data without direct-casting, but no one seems to be mentioning that).